# solve $(x^2 y+y)dy/dx =\arctan(x)$ , $y(1) = -1$

Tags: integration

solve the equation  $(x^2 y+y)(dy/dx) = \arctan(x)$ , $y(1) = -1$

my work until now

$(x^2 y+y)\,dy  = \arctan(x)\,dx$

$x^2 y\,dy+y\,dy    = \arctan(x)\,dx$    ---> stuck here

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: Divide both sides by $x^2+1\ne 0$.

Comment: separate y and x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have $$ydy = \frac{\tan^{-1}x}{1 + x^2}dx, \quad y = -1, x = 1 \tag 1$$ with a change of variable $u = \tan^{-1} x , du = \frac{dx}{1+x^2} x = 1\to u = \pi/4,$  $(1)$ becomes $$\int_{-1}^yydy = \int_{\pi/4}^uudu \to y^2 - 1 = u^2 - \pi/4, y = -\sqrt{u^2 - \pi/4 + 1} $$  therefore $$y =  -\sqrt{\tan^2 x - \pi/4 + 1} $$

Answer (score 1):

Hint 1:

$$x^2y + y = y(x^2 + 1) $$

Hint 2:

> $$\frac{d}{dx}(\arctan(x)) = \frac{1}{x^2 + 1}$$

Hint 3:

Let $f(x) = \arctan(x)$ then we have $$ \int \frac{\arctan(x) dx}{x^2 + 1} = \int f(x)f'(x) dx = \frac{f(x)^2}{2} + C.$$

Comment: where is hint 2???

Comment: @user155971 Hover your mouse over the block (click on mobile). It will appear.

Comment: I did that y(x^2+1)dy/dx=tan^-1(x) then  y*dy = [tan^-1(x)/(x^2 +1)]dx

Comment: I know integration y dy= y^2/2 but stuck here  [tan^-1(x)/(x^2 +1)]dx

Comment: See hint 3 for clarification.